# Facebook c# sdk get user id from signed request

Tags: facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

I have a minor problem in facebook c# sdk

I just want to get the facebook user id without asking for permissions , just from the signed request. Up to now i have written the code below:

```
        var current = new DefaultFacebookApplication { AppId ="***", AppSecret = "***" };

        dynamic signedRequest = FacebookSignedRequest.Parse(current, Request);


        var UserId = (string)signedRequest.Data.user.id;
```

My first question is :is that is possible? Is it possible to get the user id without oauth?
Secondly , if it is possible is the **(string)signedRequest.Data.user.id** statement correct?;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot get the Facebook user id from the signed_request **unless** they've authenticated your app.  It is a privacy issue.

Comment: Well, i used the javascript api which worked fine. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Execellent, sometimes things don't have to be done on the server.  Using the JS SDK for doing the auth is a quick way to get things done. Congrats :)